# How to set ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH in Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, configuration

How can I set `ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true` in Tomcat 8? In which file I should config this property? I want to get a URI like this `http://www.example.com//12345%2F6789`, but Tomcat does not receive the request like this with `%2F`. What should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this property in the `catalina.properties` file:

`org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true`

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done programmatically by setting the system property in the main method:

```java
System.setProperty("org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH", "true");
```